# Do we really need to add spring boot starter web for spring boot admin clients?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

Version 1.5.4 was working fine without extra declaration of starter web in POM of Spring Boot Admin Clients. When I upgraded to 2.0.1, I had to add starter web to POM to make it work. Without starter web in client apps, there is no error or no log related to registering the application.

It's not [documented](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#register-clients-via-spring-boot-admin) anywhere as far as I know. Can anyone please confirm?

Comment: can u post the exception which u were getting without the dependency?

Comment: Hi @IndraneelBende , I did not get any error in logs. I'm updating the question.

Comment: Can u post the complete log without starter web.

Comment: which log level? there was no error.. I guess starter web is a dependancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot Admin 2.x can run on netty and on tomcat. So if you want to run on tomcat you have to explicitly import the `spring-boot-starter-web`.
The getting started guide contains this dependency http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#set-up-admin-server

Comment: Hi, I am talking about clients(http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#register-clients-via-spring-boot-admin) and not server. Spring boot admin server is working fine..

Comment: yes you should import the web-starter for your clients imho it was a misconception in 1.5.x that the client-starter did import it.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for the answer!